# Count on List<String>[]

Tags: c#

I have a document that contains following:

```
    1> Id: "10204"; FromCity:"Vadodara"; ToCity:"Surat"; OfficeId:{"office1","Office2","Office3"} // row-1
    2> Id: "10205"; FromCity:"Ahmedabad"; ToCity:"Surat"; OfficeId:{"office2","Office3","Office4"} // row-2
```

Then my output should be:

```
    office1 - 1;
    Office2 - 2;
    Office3 - 2;
    Office4 - 1;
```

Please help me out for this using LINQ. I have splitted Array and its single count for single document.

```
var OfficeID = results2
                .GroupBy(frm => new { frm.ItemNumber },
                (key, group) => new
                {
                    Key1 = key.ItemNumber,
                    Count = group.Sum(e => e.Count)
                });
```

thanks in Advance 
I did this:

```
        var OfficeId= results2.SelectMany(@class => @class.ItemNumber)
            .GroupBy(s => s).Select(a => new { officeId = a, count = a.Count() });


        foreach (var i in OfficeId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.officeId+"\t"+i.count);
        }
```

But I dont get OfficeId names displayed in loop

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Input: top code block. Desired output: second code block. What they have tried: third code block. What they want in "question form": a count of the number of occurences of each distinct office ID in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string[] officeId { get; set; }
}

var objects = new List<MyClass>
                  {
                      new MyClass{id=1, officeId=new[]{"office1","Office2","Office3"}},
                      new MyClass {id=2,officeId=new[]{"office1","Office2","Office3"}},
                      new MyClass{id=3, officeId=new[]{"office1","Office2","Office3"}}
                  };


var enumerable = objects.SelectMany(@class => @class.officeId).GroupBy(s => s).Select(a => new { officeId = a.Key, count = a.Count() });
```

Comment: var OfficeId= results2.SelectMany(@class => @class.ItemNumber)
                .GroupBy(s => s).Select(a => new { officeId = a, count = a.Count() });
            

            foreach (var i in OfficeId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.officeId+"\t"+i.count);
            }

Comment: I did this:var OfficeId= results2.SelectMany(@class => @class.ItemNumber)
                .GroupBy(s => s).Select(a => new { officeId = a, count = a.Count() });
            

            foreach (var i in OfficeId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.officeId+"\t"+i.count);
            }

Comment: Sorry had some issue with the code. Edited. Please check. Changed `a.Key` in the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

**Step1:** Create Custom Class as below to hold your data.

```
public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FromCity { get; set; }
        public string ToCity { get; set; }
        public List<string> OfficeIds { get; set; }
    }
```

**Step2:** This step just fills dummy data, you don't require it.

```
List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();

            //row 1
            documents.Add(new Document()
            {
                Id = 10204,
                FromCity = "Vadodara",
                ToCity = "Surat",
                OfficeIds = new List<string>() { "Office2", "Office2", "Office3" }

            });

            //row 2
            documents.Add(new Document()
            {
                Id = 10205,
                FromCity = "Ahmedabad",
                ToCity = "Surat",
                OfficeIds = new List<string>() { "Office2", "Office3", "Office4" }

            });
```

**Step3:** Use SelectMany in LINQ to convert into list of office string values.

```
List<string> lstOffice  = documents.SelectMany(d => d.OfficeIds).ToList();
```

**Step4:** Filter data using where clause

```
Console.WriteLine("Office1 " +  lstOffice.Where(s => s.ToLower() == "office1").Count().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Office2 " +  lstOffice.Where(s => s.ToLower() == "office2").Count().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Office3 " +  lstOffice.Where(s => s.ToLower() == "office3").Count().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Office4 " +  lstOffice.Where(s => s.ToLower() == "office4").Count().ToString());
```